# British Cycling Attire

Tags: clothes, vintage

How can I find the correct outfit for a British Cycling event?

http://www.abcetour.com

```
NO sign-up, NO fees, NO lycra, just wander in!
```

I am strictly a Lycra guy... now what will I wear? ;)

But seriously, if anyone can point to a good resource for Vintage bike attire that would be great.

Comment: Product recs are considered off-topic on here, so I'd excpect tyhis question to be closed. But to try to help....a lot of jerseys back in the day were made of Merino wool, so you might have some joy googling that. For example there are a bunch at [Bromley Video](http://www.bromleyvideo.com/shop/shop.php?maincat=8&sid=sid08f857ea6be0dfcb3cb4b27592e2e31c) that might be considered "retro". None particularly British/English though.

Comment: Thanks Pete - I can delete my post if it angers anyone - re: Off topic silly clothing post

Comment: It won't "anger" anyone, we're quite a nice bunch on here! (mostly) It's just that this type of question doesn't really fit with the site ethos - you're asking something which can't really have a "correct" answer. My other thought was to look for something by [Rapha](http://www.rapha.cc/gb/en/shop-/jerseys/category/jerseys) - they're British and make exactly the kind of overpriced clothing you might expect to see at a Gentlemen's' Cycling Event ;-)

Comment: Its one of those questions with lots of reasons to close it, but its a cool question to have on the site.

Comment: I'd lend you my 20 yo (Italian) wool road top and my (Italian) cycling shorts (or maybe the longs), but I'm in Australia, and they definitely want British Best :-) Seriously, maybe some traditional cross country ski gear would do.

Comment: I feel it is important to differentiate what you refer to as `British Cycling` from http://www.britishcycling.org.uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the ABCE Tour website has a section specifically about the [dress code](http://www.abcetour.com/).  In the [photo](http://www.imageevent.com/abce) section you can see what others have been wearing in the past.  Some of the past attendees even wore jeans and t-shirts.  So it shouldn't be to difficult.  Check out your local second hand and thrift store if you want to purchase something specific for this event.

Answer (score 1):

For "Vintage" attire, try your local second-hand or thrift store. They will likely have clothing and shoes that will pass muster, and for pennies on the pound. If you really want to go the extra mile, and have basic sewing skills, you can [make your own knickers from wool slacks](http://www.appleblock.com/knickers.php).

For comfort, I don't care how "lycra-free" and event is supposed to be, I am wearing a pair of standard bike shorts or a padded liner underneath my slacks.